How to set up NavHost for android UI testing?
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot navigate to NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/movies/ }. Navigation graph has not been set for NavController androidx.navigation.testing.TestNavHostController@1d694be.
I don't know how to set the navigation graph for navHost explicitly
How to provide tests like this?
ScreenTest:
@Composable
fun TestNavGraph(navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "start") {
        composable("start") { Text("Start Screen") }
        composable("movies/") { Text("Movies Screen") }
        composable("movies/{movieId}") { backStackEntry ->
            val movieId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("movieId")
            Text("Movie Details Screen for $movieId")
        }
    }
}

class ScreensTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createAndroidComposeRule<MainActivity>()

    @Test
    fun testMoviesNavigation() {
        // Create a test NavController
        val navController = TestNavHostController(composeTestRule.activity)
        val screens = Screens(navController)

        // Setup your Composable with the TestNavHostController
        composeTestRule.activity.setContent {
            TestNavGraph(navController = navController)
        }

        // Perform navigation
        screens.movies()

        // Assert navigation action
        assertEquals("movies/", navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route)
    }

    @Test
    fun testMovieDetailsNavigation() {
        // Create a test NavController
        val navController = TestNavHostController(composeTestRule.activity)
        val screens = Screens(navController)

        // Setup your Composable with the TestNavHostController
        composeTestRule.setContent {
            screens.movieDetails(42)
        }

        // Perform navigation
        screens.movieDetails(42)

        // Assert navigation action
        assertEquals("movies/42", navController.currentBackStackEntry?.destination?.route)
    }
}

Screens class I'm testing:
package com.romahduda.movies30.navigation

import androidx.navigation.NavHostController
import com.romahduda.movies30.util.Constants.MOVIES_SCREEN

class Screens(navController: NavHostController) {
    val movies: () -> Unit = {
        navController.navigate("movies/"){
            popUpTo(MOVIES_SCREEN) {inclusive = true}
        }
    }

    val movieDetails: (Int) -> Unit = {movieId ->
        navController.navigate("movies/$movieId")
    }
}

I created TestNavGraph for this test but it didn't resolved the problem
